# Image filter with javascript

Tags: javascript, imagefilter

I am new to web development. I am trying to create my photography webpage. I have created a basic html design.
I want to filter the image when the specific button is clicked. I went through the w3schools code about it but could not get quite clear about it. Not with the JQuery.
Here is my html code with buttons.
Thank you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Gallery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <div id="myBtnContainer">
    <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')">ALL</button>
    <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')">Nature</button>
    <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')">Animal</button>

  </div>
  <!--grid-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column_nature">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="images/nature.jpg" style="width:40%">
        <h4>Nature</h4>
        <p>This is me</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column_nature">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="images/swan.jpg" style="width:40%">
      <h4>Swan</h4>

    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more clarity on what exactly you want? I.e. what do you mean by filter then out? What do you actually want to happen?

Additionally, please provide the code within your Script Tag script.js and even your CSS file in style.css.

Comment: I mean when I click Nature it should show only nature pic and when I click animal, it should show only the image of swan. I have only written those script and css link as start.

Comment: Okay, so what's happening then, is when you click, you're telling it to perform a JavaScript function, which is not written, so it isn't actually doing anything. I will provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because both of your images had 'nature' on them, a filter would not have had any effect. I adapted your code to the [w3schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_portfolio_filter.asp), but changed it so that the first image had 'nature' as a filter , and the second had 'bird' as a filter.

Incidentally, there is no underscore between the column and the filter name (If you put one in, as you did in your code) it won't work. I adapted this too.

Best of luck

```js
/*this goes in your script.js*/

filterSelection("all") // Execute the function and show all columns
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  // Add the "show" class (display:block) to the filtered elements, and remove the "show" class from the elements that are not selected
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

// Show filtered elements
function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className += " " + arr2[i];
    }
  }
}

// Hide elements that are not selected
function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1); 
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
/*this bit will go into your style.css file*/

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

/* Center website */
.main {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    word-break: break-all;
}

.row {
    margin: 8px -16px;
}

/* Add padding BETWEEN each column (if you want) */
.row,
.row > .column {
    padding: 8px;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    display: none; /* Hide columns by default */
}

/* Clear floats after rows */ 
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

/* Content */
.content {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */
.show {
    display: block;
}

/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add a grey background color on mouse-over */
.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Add a dark background color to the active button */
.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Gallery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <div id="myBtnContainer">
    <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')">ALL</button>
    <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('nature')">Nature</button>
    <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('bird')">Animal</button>

  </div>
  <!--grid-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column nature">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/257360/pexels-photo-257360.jpeg" style="width:40%">
        <h4>Nature</h4>
        <p>This is me</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column bird">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://www.phrases.org.uk/images/swan-song-1.jpg" style="width:40%">
      <h4>Swan</h4>

    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When you add other images with existing filter names, e.g. nature (but a different image), then you can display groups of images on click.

Comment: btw, the javascript given is not jQuery, just plain javascript.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you're new to programming; so beware that some users may provide you with answers suggesting you install jQuery, or Bootstrap - which while that it entirely true and what I would recommend - I equally understand that these all provide steep learning curves for a beginner.

As such, you can develop in HTML, CSS, and the naked JavaScript library as standard. So I have provided a solution to your problem in the code below, and documented my code also, so that you may better understand it.

Replace your code, with my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Gallery</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<div id="myBtnContainer">
    <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('All')">ALL</button>
    <button class="btn active" 
 onclick="filterSelection('Nature')">Nature</button>
    <button class="btn active" 
 onclick="filterSelection('Swan')">Animal</button>

</div>
<!--grid-->
<div class="row">
    <div class="column_nature filter" id="Nature">
        <div class="content">
            <img src="images/nature.jpg" style="width:40%">
            <h4>Nature</h4>
            <p>This is me</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 

 <div class="column_nature filter" id="Swan">
<div class="content">
            <img src="images/swan.jpg" style="width:40%">
            <h4>Swan</h4>

        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
   <script>
   // Function to hide all other elements, bar the parameter provided
    function filterSelection(elementToShow){
    if(elementToShow != "All"){ 
    // Get an array of elements with the class name, filter.
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("filter");
    // For each of them
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    // Make them invisible
    x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    // Get and then make the one you want, visible
    var y = document.getElementById(elementToShow).style.display = "block";
    }
    else{ // If the parameter provided is all, we want to display everything
    // Get an array of elements with the class name, filter.
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("filter");
    // For each of them
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    //Make them visible
    x[i].style.display = "block";
    }
    }

    }
    </script>
  </body>   
  </html>
```

Please note the following; if you add a new button to filter something else, you must give it an * onclick="filterSelection('x')" * where the x is the name of that which you want to filter. Then on the div you want to keep, simply give it a class with the same name as "x".

So for instance, if I had a button:

```
<button onclick="filterSelection('Mountains')">Mountains</button>
```

Then I would expect that if I click it, that all filter class divs would be hidden, except for the div that had the class mountains. So I would have to have a div like so:

```
<div class="filter Mountains">This would be the div that would be displayed on click of the above button, and all others would be hidden.</div>
```

I hope this helps provide you with the answer you were looking for, although eventually it would be best to look into Bootstrap or jQuery which will be much more sustainable in the long run.